# Remembering DropDownList state when redirecting

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, redirect

I have DropDownList, which has some options to choose from. Now after when user selects one of the options, it has to click on a button, which is a redirection on the same page:

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Graphs.aspx?Selection=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "&Date1=" + TextBox1.Text + "&Date2=" + TextBox2.Text);
}
```

I have to use redirection instead of postback, because I use flot which is javascript library and all the code has to be written again when user selects some other option. The problem is, when it redirects back, for some reason I can't make it to remember the value in the DropDownList, which has user previously selected. I tried this with this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["Selection"] == "TemperatureOUT")
    {
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else if (Request.QueryString["Selection"] == "Dewpoint")
    {
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

The problem is, if for example user selects Dewpoint from DropDownList and then clicks on a button, which causes redirection, the new url should have:

```
Graphs.aspx?Selection=Dewpoint&...
```

but instead, it says:

```
 Graphs.aspx?Selection=TemperatureOUT&...
```

Now if I remove that code from Page_Load it works, but it does not remember what has user selected before. Now I know that there has to be something with Page_Load. Isn't that when page is redirected, the Page_Load get's called, so it should look a the Selection value and print it out. So it has to be a problem with redirection, that for some reason does not set the selected value.

Comment: Have client side redirection instead of server side. There's no real point in having server side button that all it does is redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is the one you are asking for

```
DropDownList oldvalue = (DropDownList)PreviousPage.FindControl("DropDownList1");
```

Try by writing like this

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("Your first page drop down id here");
        if (ddl!=null)
        {
          if(ddl.SelectedValue == "2")
            // do your coding here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I implemented it like this:DropDownList oldvalue = (DropDownList)PreviousPage.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        if (oldvalue != null)
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = oldvalue.SelectedIndex;
        }

Comment: I enabled debug and the line that causes this:DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("DropDownList1"); Isn't that strange?

Comment: Did u get the previous selected value

Comment: Don't know, because I get Server Error! I was looking on google and found that it could be because I am using Response.Redirect, that's why it causes Page.PreviousPage being null, but tried Server.Transfer and still no clue. Any more hints?

Comment: Ok, I added this: if (Page.PreviousPage != null), now I don't get the error, but I assume, that everytime I do the redirect, the Page.PreviousPage = null, because it does not select the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is that you are using `IsPostBack` to determine what items to add to your list:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(...)
}
```

If you make changes to the list without safely determining whether it should be a GET or POST operation, the list items will get rebound (assuming you adding them in code not markup). When the page loads through POST, it restores the state of the controls (that being the items added in this case), and then applies any changes (like selected item, etc.) before handling the load event.

When you do a redirect, you are issuing a new GET request for the redirect target, which will render the page without processing the selection. With a combination of `IsPostBack` and handling the querystring on a GET request, that should be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the options are static, so the DropDownList items does not change. What you meand by that: "you are issuing a new GET request for the redirect target, which will render the page without processing the selection."? I don't get it why it would not obey DropDownList1.SelectedValue?

Comment: Matthew has the right solution, but misunderstood your problem. Your Page_Load handler fires BEFORE your Button4_Click handler. That means that when you click the button, if there is any "Selection" value in the querystring, it will use that to change the dropdownlist's selected value before you get a chance to look at it in your click handler. You need to wrap your code in Page_Load with the check for !IsPostback so that it will ignore the querystring when you click the button, and will use whatever they selected in the dropdownlist.

Comment: If you edit your answer and remove the stuff about adding new items to the ddl (which is not trying to do) and put his code in your if block, then it would make more sense.